# Chrome extension, SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, import

I'm working on a project and I have to create a chrome extension which filters reviews in amazon.
Anyway my problem is connecting two javascript files because I get the error "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module".

script.js is the file that runs when the chrome extension is activated.
makeCall.js is the file I want to call inside script.js and it makes an axios call on a server.

here the codes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7NFY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72djx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Oeqo.png)